# Is uniform convergence and pointwise convergence the same in function space C[X,R]?

Tags: metric-spaces

In GF Simmon's book on Topology, I came across the definitions of
point wise convergence of a sequence of functions and uniform convergence of a sequence of functions.

For all future references,
$C[X,R]$ is the set of continuous bounded real functions defined on the metric space $X,$ and $B$ is the subset of all bounded real functions on $X.$

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real functions defined on $X.$

Pointwise convergence is when if for each point $x\in X,$ the sequence of real functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges to a function
$f(x)$, i.e., at each $x,$ for a given $\varepsilon$, there exists a natural $N$ such that for all $n>N, $ $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$.

Uniform Convergence is when the $\varepsilon$ doesn't depend on $x.$ Which means that a natural $N$ can be found for each $\varepsilon$ such that it works for all $x\in X.$

In terms of convergence of the sequence of functions to a function,
Pointwise means that for a given $\varepsilon$ you will find an $N$ for each $x\in X.$
Uniform means that for a given $\varepsilon$ you will find an $N$ which works for all $x\in X.$
Am I right?

Comment: Writing $f_n(x)$-$f(x)$ rather than $f_n(x)-f(x)$ is not proper MathJax usage. See my edits to this question.

Comment: Dear @MichaelHardy, Thanks for your kindness. I am learning.

Answer (score 1):

Well, strictly speaking, the quantifiers in your last paragraph are not okay. Actually, it should be: "Pointwise mean that for a $\varepsilon>0$, and for each $x\in X$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that...". Can you see the difference? We talk first about the point $x\in X$. Your understanding of uniform convergence is correct.

With respect to the title of you question, these kind of convergence are not the same, even when $X$ is compact. Consider $X=[0,1]$, the sequence $f_n(x)=x^n$ converge pointwise to a function which is not even continuous,  despite of that, the sequence does not have a uniform limit (since the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous).

Comment: There is no difference between "$\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\forall x \in X$, ..." and "$\forall x \in X$, $\forall \varepsilon > 0$..." The quantified definition of pointwise convergence in the OP's post is correct.

Comment: He wrote: "you will find an $N$ for each $x\in X$". That can be written as $\exists N\forall x$, which is not the same that $\forall x\exists N$.

Comment: I did not talk about the "for all" quantifiers, I referred to the "existence" one, before the "each x\in X".

Comment: "You will find an $N$ for each $x \in X$". is not $\exists N, \forall x$. That would be "you will find an $N$ *such that* for each $x \in X$"...

Comment: Dear @EmmanuelC, I believe what you have written in your first comment is just right. I had meant just that: there exists an N for each x in X, and not for all x in X there exists an N.